# Request 20.000 request per second in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to make 20000 request (`PUT`, `POST`, `GET`) per second.
Please see construction:

```
TestPlan
  ThreadGroup
  (Number of Threads):20000
  (Ramp-Up Period): 1
  HTTP GET Request
  HTTP PUT Request
  HTTP POST Request
```

But this construction does not request 20000 per second. May be I forget to add some other case?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts as follows:

1. It starts defined number of threads within the bounds of ramp-up period
2. Threads start executing [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [logic controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
3. When there are no more samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread is being shut down

The throughput (number of requests per second) mostly depends on your application response time, given you have 3 requests and 20 000 threads the response time has to be around 300 milliseconds in order to produce 20 000 requests per second. If it will be higher - the throughput will be lower.

If your target is to simulate the load of 20 000 requests per second I would recommend going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination. They can be connected together via [Schedule Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function), this way JMeter will automatically kick off required number of threads in order to reach and maintain the target number of requests per second.

P.S. Depending on your application response time you might need much higher number of threads than 20000 so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as default JMeter setup is not suitable for such a high load. You might also need to consider [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)